# Make a div childrens appear one by one

Tags: jquery, image, loops, load

I am trying to make a basic image distributor using jquery.

What I have done: When I click on an empty image, it is loaded and displayed. [Demo](http://lab.raphaelbastide.com/tools/distributeImg/index.html)

```
$(".pic").click(function() {
    var src = $(this).attr('rel');
    $(this).attr('src', src);
});
```

[edit] I want to fill every image src in the the .pile div, one by one, each time I click on the `<body>`.

I know I need to use a loop or something like that but I am not really confortable with that. Thank you for any help.

My HTML content:

```
<div class="pile">
    <img class="pic" rel="3.jpg" src=""/>
    <img class="pic" rel="2.jpg" src=""/>
    <img class="pic" rel="1.jpg" src=""/>
</div>
```

Comment: What's your question?  I know you want help writing some code, but we need a more specific question to be of some help.

Comment: When you say body you mean <body>?

Comment: I don't know if I understand correctly: Do you want to add a new image tag to your div tag? Where do you have your list?

Comment: You say that you want to populate the `src` attribute each time you click on an image. It looks like you figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure this is what you meant but here is the code to have each img appear one at a time whenever the page is clicked.

```
var $currentImg;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $currentImg = $('#pile img:first'); //get the first img from the pile div

    $("html").click(function() {
        var src = $currentImg.attr('rel');
        $currentImg.attr('src', src);
        $currentImg = $currentImg.next();
    });
});
```

This assumes the images you want are in the `<div>` tag with the id of pile.

Note that I wrapped your original code inside of `$(document).ready(function(){ .... });`. You were probably testing this locally and didn't notice, but without that thing I added your page would only sometimes work.

Comment: Yes ! That is perfect ! pile is a class, my fault. Thank you @Anton

Comment: Opps my bad. If its a class that line should have said  $currentImg = $('.pile img:first');

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about something like this?:

```
$(".pile").click(function() {

    var target = $(this).find("img[src='']").first();

    var src = target.attr('rel');
    target.attr('src', src);

});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/xmQbq/1/

Comment: I think you accidentally got the wrong link, because when I click on it there is nothing but a blank jsfiddle page.